# Custom url is not working with drealty listing

Tags: 7

I am using [Drealty](https://www.drupal.org/project/drealty) module in Drupal 7. I have created custom url for properties.

I am getting path using;

`<a href="<?php print drupal_get_path_alias("drealty_listing/$id"); ?>"><?php print t('More Detail'); ?></a>`

This code is not working for me properly. For some properties it gives *page not found* but *Property* exists.

Answer (score 0):

Using the url() function should give you what you need:

`<a href="<?php print url("drealty_listing/$id"); ?>"><?php print t('More Detail'); ?></a>`

The url will be converted automatically to the alias.

Comment: Its working as well my code that I mention above.. still getting same issue for some listings.

Comment: Do you have a link to the pages with the problem?

Comment: Yes I have a link.

Comment: I mean a link to where you are having the problem to clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Issue is link is showing page not found. But when i click on edit . Property is available.